# Transform elements of an array into objects / Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a challenge to create a simple Notes manager in JS, I've written a function that takes **one** string, gives it and id and pushes it to an array of notes.

```
let nextId = 0;
const getId = () => nextId++;
let notes = [{id: getId(), value: 'Note'}];

const addNote = (input) => {
notes.push({id:getId(), value: input});
console.log('Note added');
```

I now struggle with a function that will take **multiple** strings as parameters

```
('own', 'snail', 'platypus')
```

create an object for each element with id/value(string) and push it to the main array.

The result should look like:

```
[{ id: 1, value: 'owl'},
 { id: 2, value: 'snail'}]
```

So far I have this, it assigns ID correctly, but the loop fails

```
const batchAddNotes = (values) => {
let obj = {};
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    obj.id = (getId());
    obj.value = (values[i]);}
return obj;};
```

Comment: Have you tried using the functions arguments object? It's an array of all the arguments that are being passed to a function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: just replace `(values) => {` with `(...values) => {`

Answer (score 1):

To have your variables in a certain scope, I'd pack it all in a class (or a function). As you're using arrow functions, the class should be ok. To add multiple nodes the way you've shown; using var-args, you can create a method that expects those with `(...input)`

```js
class Notes {
  constructor() {
    this.nextId = 0;
    this.nodes = [{
      id: this.getId(),
      value: 'Note'
    }];
  }

  addNote(input) {
    this.nodes.push({
      id: this.getId(),
      value: input
    })
  }

  getId() {
    return this.nextId++;
  }

  addNotes(...input) {
    input.forEach(e => this.addNote(e));
  }
}

const notes = new Notes();
notes.addNotes('own', 'snail', 'platypus');
console.log(notes.nodes);
```

Comment: Why do you go for a OOP solution for a clearly "functional" example ? OOP is most of the time kinda Overengineering IMHO.

Comment: One reason is that your code will likely break should he come to the idea to use nextId anywhere else in his code again. @CristianS. I don't think that OOP is overengineering, but it's ok to have different opinions on that.

Comment: For sure! It depends a lot on what is he exactly trying to achieve. Normally variables like let are scoped in a module or something depending on which framework or tech-stack you use. But yeah... there is no white and black :D

Comment: My point was more meant to be in the same file as whole project @CristianS. You've definitely a point, for the task at hand it might be overkill to create a class for that, but I believe in a real world app, with a lot of code, the OOP style always wins. Again, only my opinion... :-)

Comment: @bambam See my answer, specially the more functional approach :D There's an alternative to OOP. OOP is good, but I'm not intoxicated anymore. OOP not always wins

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions arguments object. It's an array of all the arguments that are being passed to a function. Then you can loop over them and run your functionality on them each time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) passed in your function as var args

```
const addNote = _ => {
     for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
           notes.push({id:getId(), value: arguments[i]});
           console.log('Note added');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [rest params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) :

```js
const myFn = (...values) => {
  let tmpArr = [];
  for(let i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++){
    tmpArr.push({
      id : i + 1,
      value : values[i]
    });
  }
  return tmpArr;
}

const result = myFn('own', 'snail', 'platypus');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it look like when using Rest Params and reusing your first function. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

You can add so many notes as you want (`addMultipleNotes` can receive indefinite number of arguments )

```js
let nextId = 0;
const getId = () => nextId++;
let notes = [{id: getId(), value: 'Note'}];

const addSingleNote = (input) => {
    notes.push({id:getId(), value: input});
    console.log('Note added');
};

const addMultipleNotes = (...args) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        addSingleNote(args[i]);
    }
};

addMultipleNotes('one', 'two', 'three');
console.log(notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note how I've used an IIFE and a closure to create an `id` generator.

In the other hand, *rest parameters*, `Array#map` and parameter spread are your friends:

```js
const incrId = (() => {
  let id = 0

  return () => ++id
})()

const valuesToNotes = (...values) => values.map(value => ({
  id: incrId(),
  value
}))

const notes = []

// Parameter spread (i.e. '...') gives each
// array item in the output of valuesToNotes
// as if you would use Function#apply
notes.push(...valuesToNotes('a', 'b', 'c'))

console.log(notes)
```

Yet another more functional approach which doesn't mutate the input `notes` and produces a new one with existing notes plus the ones transformed from `values`:

```js
const concat = xs => ys => xs.concat(ys)
const map = f => xs => xs.map(f)
const pipe = xs => x => xs.reduce((r, f) => f(r), x)

const incrId = (() => {
  let id = 0

  return () => ++id
})()

const valueToNote = value => ({
  id: incrId(),
  value
})

const notes = []
const appendNotes = pipe([map(valueToNote), concat(notes)])
const moreNotes = appendNotes(['a', 'b', 'c'])

console.log(moreNotes)
```